# Can a VB6 component be compiled to 64 bit?

Tags: com, vb6, 64-bit

Is there a way to compile a VB6 component into 64 bits?

My feeling is that the answer is "no", but I would like to confirm this.

Please, if you can, paste a link to an authorative source that would confirm.

Comment: 32 bits barely existed when VB6 was written, let alone 64!

Comment: @John Saunders: My sarcasm detectors are a bit off.

Comment: It's not sarcasm, it's a fact, isn't it?

Comment: Windows NT 3.1: first 32-bit windows, July 1993. Visual Basic 6, 1998. First 64-bit Windows in 2003. So VB6 came 5 years after 32-bit and 5 years before 64-bit. (Not funny, but I think it's accurate. I was up early today and my sense of humour has faded.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No. I hope [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx) counts as authoritative.

> **64-Bit Windows** 
>   
> Visual Basic 6.0
>   runtime files are 32-bit.  These files
>   ship in 64-bit Windows Operating
>   Systems referenced in the table below.
>   32-bit VB6 applications and components
>   are supported in the WOW emulation
>   environment only.  32-bit components
>   must also be hosted in 32-bit
>   application processes.
>
> The Visual Basic 6.0 IDE has never
>   been offered in a native 64-bit
>   version, nor has the 32-bit IDE been
>   supported on 64-bit Windows.  VB6
>   development on 64-bit Windows is not
>   and will not be supported.

Comment: vb6 doesn't even have a 64 bit integer type. To get a filesize you actually have to call the Windows API by passing in a Currency type, because that is the only vb6 type large enough to hold the 64 bit return value. Then you have to multiply by 1000 to get the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

No it cannot (well Microsoft has not released a compiler to compile it for a 64-bit environment), but this does not mean that it won't run on a 64-bit system.  To run it in conjunction with IIS, you'll need to install the 32-bit version of IIS.

Comment: The question is about VB6, not VBScript. What's IIS got to do with it?

Comment: Well there are Web Classes, and then for that matter VB6 libraries called from classic ASP (same thing really).  Then there were OLEISAPI2 and similar shims for using VB6 to write ISAPI applications.

Comment: Well, forgive me for being presumptious, but normally when someone asks about compiling in 64-bit they want to know if they can get it to run on a 64-bit server.  IIS comes into play, because most systems which are 64-bit are servers meaning they are generally web/com servers.  VB6 was the major language to write com components for business systems.  I was pointing out that in a pinch you can get a vb6 component to run in 64-bit system even when it's an ASP web application.