# Windows 8 permission havoc on VB6 Shell Call

Tags: windows, shell, permissions, vb6, windows-8.1

I'm attempting to call a command prompt to copy a text file to a port in a compiled OCX written in VB6. It's doing this via the copy command in command prompt, sending a text file to a port like "LPT1", etc. This works great on XP and on 7, but Windows 8 will not allow it to happen. I've taken the following steps:

- Make the service using this OCX run under a specific administrator's account instead of the local system's account
- Use "ShellExecute" in the VB6 code, ensuring to use the correct syntax. (This works on Windows 7 fine, but again fails in Windows 8)
- Make an executable out of a batch file that included the Administrator manifest, but no dice.
- I've made sure to register the OCX as administrator each and every time

Due to the command working on both Windows XP and 7, I'm inclined to believe this is a permissions issue with Windows 8, but all of the workarounds have failed so far. If more information is required, please let me know and I will provide it. Thanks!

Edit: I've found out that the OCX behaves properly under debugging... My guess is that the debugging of the OCX grants it the privileges that the IDE has, which is Visual Studio 6.

Edit: As requested, here is the original ShellAndWait code written in VB6 that is used to start a cmd console.

```
Public Function ShellAndWait(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal eAppStyle As VbAppWinStyle) As Boolean
Dim lPID As Long

     'Default to not found'
      m_lShellHandle = 0
     'run the program'
     lPID = Shell(FilePath, eAppStyle)
     ' Check for errors'
     If lPID = 0 Then
       ShellAndWait = False
       Exit Function
     End If

    'The command console window is tough to get a hold of, so'
    'that's the reason there are two attempts before moving on'
    'and the delays, allow time for window to start'
    DoEvents
    Sleep 500

    'Find the window handle'
    EnumWindows AddressOf FindThread, lPID
     'Not found - Try finding again (more aggressive wait)'
     If m_lShellHandle = 0 Then
        Sleep (1000)
        EnumWindows AddressOf FindThread, lPID
    End If
    'Make sure we have a valid window'
    If m_lShellHandle <> 0 Then
        'Keep checking to see if window is still available'
        Do While IsWindow(m_lShellHandle)
             'Allow repaint'
             DoEvents
            'Allow other processes to run'
            SleepEx 300, True
        Loop
    End If

    ShellAndWait = True
End Function
```

Comment: Please tell me, what exactly do you mean: "copy a text file to a port"?

Comment: Did the change to Windows 8 involve changing from 32 bit to 64 bit?  If so, it likely broke all the Declare Functions in your OCX.  (64 bit requires PtrSafe declarations).

Comment: Thomas, you can use the "Copy" command from command prompt like so:
copy "TextFileNamehere.txt" "PrinterPort" to print a text file straight to a port. I apologize, I should have said so.

Comintern, I see what you mean. I had this thought as well, but confirmed that upon running the debugger on the OCX, it elevated it to the same rights that VB6 has on Windows 8 and was able to call the command.

I'm not sure why this warranted a negative 2 rating, but as long as I can get some hints going around, I'm cool with whatever rating ;)

Comment: Do you have the source code for the OCX? I would probably be *a lot* easier if I could see how it is using ShellExecute.  I'm still wondering if the old environment was 32bit and the new one 64bit.  That changes a lot of external function invocations from VB.

Comment: @Comintern, I think you're on to something here... I thought I had checked into that, but evidently not enough. I say this because I activated Windows 8's TRUE admin account, logged the service on as this account, and still the command fails... Permissions seem less and less likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted provides the answer, and the problem is the call to EnumWindows.  VB6 doesn't have a 64 bit compiler available, and any  VB6 application would be declaring the EnumWindows function similarly to:

```
Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As _
Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
```

The problem is that the first argument is a function pointer for a callback, and a Long is a 32bit memory address, and the AddressOf operator will only return 32 bits of the callback address.  To my knowledge, there is no real way to declare an API function to accept a 64bit pointer in VB6.  In fact, as mentioned in the comments above, 64bit Office required an extention to the VBA runtime to allow the use of LongPtr types and PtrSafe declarations for API calls that were 64bit safe. You'll find more information about this in the question ['Can a VB6 component be compiled to 64 bit?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167102/can-a-vb6-component-be-compiled-to-64-bit) and the [Office Dev Center page for PtrSafe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278832.aspx).

It is likely running fine in the context of the debugger because it is running inside of the WOW environment, but would fail if called from another context because it will try to start in a non-WOW context.

While there *might* be some workarounds, it would involve stripping out the vast majority of the native API calls.  As the comment says though, "The command console window is tough to get a hold of, so..." it would likely be easier to port this to .NET.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed and informative answer. Despite this question netting negative ratings, I have learned something from it and appreciate your time and effort! Thank you very much.